# (Selenium) after itunes connect login, i'v got unexpected results for driver.page_source

Tags: python, selenium

environment : Selenium+python

after itunes connect login, i'v got unexpected results for driver.page_source.
(https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app)

i'v to find page elements but i can't found anything.

i think result of different url

give me some advice

**i tried:**

```
ENTER = u'\ue007'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "aid-auth-widget-iFrame")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='account_name_text_field']")))

if(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='account_name_text_field']").is_displayed()):
    inputID = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='account_name_text_field']")
    inputID.send_keys("id")
    time.sleep(1)
    inputID.send_keys(ENTER)

while(True):
    flag = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password_text_field']").is_displayed()
    if(flag):
        inputPW = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password_text_field']")
        inputPW.send_keys('password')
        inputPW.send_keys(ENTER)
        break

print(driver.page_source)
```

**result body**

```
<body itc-document-click animation-control ng-controller="pageWrapperController" ng-class="{ 'is-homepage': currentPage == 'Homepage', 'is-not-homepage': currentPage != 'Homepage', 'body-loading': !isLoaded, 'is-flexbox': wrapperclass == 'pane-layout-page-wrapper','useSFFont':referenceData.useSFFont }">

    <div id="pageWrapper" class="{{ wrapperclass }}  {{ 'loc_' + l10n.interpolate('ITC.current.locale.metadata') }}" ng-class="{'saving':isSaving }" ng-cloak>

        <div class="wrapper-loader" ng-class="{'loading': !isLoaded}" id="main-wrapper-loader"></div>

        <div  id="header" ng-include="'/itc/views/shared/_header.7a8bd642cd.html'" itc-fixed-main-nav></div>
        <div id="holiday_header" ng-class="{'show':(hasContentProviderFeature('WINTER_SHUTDOWN') || hasContentProviderFeature('WINTER_PRE_SHUTDOWN')) && $root.currentState !== 'contract_interstital'}">
            <h2 ng-bind-html="l10n.interpolate('ITC.HolidayShutdownBanner.Title')"></h2>
            <p ng-bind-html="l10n.interpolate('ITC.HolidayShutdownBanner.Text')"></p>
        </div>

        <div ui-view class="flexcol" ng-class="{'no-messaging': hasNoMessaging }" id="main-ui-view"></div>


    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="footer" ng-include="'/itc/views/shared/_footer.9af07d1f40.html'" ng-class="{ 'homepage-footer': currentPage == 'Homepage', 'internal-footer': currentPage != 'Homepage', 'sidebar-page': hasSidebar }"></div>

    <script src="/itc/js/compiled/lib/vendor.16d4284eeb.js"></script>
    <script src="/itc/js/sb.36222ef449.js"></script>
    <script data-main="/itc/js/ng-app/main.bd74ba18d7.js" src="/itc/js/compiled/lib/require.min.947b91fc0e.js"></script>
    <script>
    /************* DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! **************/
    <!--
    if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE')>=0)document.write(unescape('%3C')+'\!-'+'-')
    //--></script><noscript><img src="http://metrics.apple.com/b/ss/appleitmsna/1/H.24--NS/0"
    height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" /></noscript>
</body>
```

Comment: Please paste error message.

Comment: there is not some error. just the result was different things that my thinking I want to find `<a ng-href="appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/…" target="_self" ng-if="!nav.down" href="appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/…">` ....